# List<>.Append doesn't work for public, static, and initialized field

Tags: c#

I wrote some code in order to add an object to my `public static List<Tuple<TasksTypes, string>>() TasksToDo`, but when I try to `Append()` the list nothing happends - it stays the same although in the debuagger the method is called, and there are no exceptions. here is my relevant code:

```
    public class GetRefreshInfo : IDisposable
    {
        public enum TasksTypes
        {
            GetOneTable,
            GetAllBySpecial,
        }
        private static List<Tuple<TasksTypes, string>> TasksToDo = null;
        public double RefreshFreq { get; set; } = 300;
        public GetRefreshInfo(double RefreshFreqPar = 300)
        {
            //<summary>Object Constructor</summary>
            RefreshFreq = RefreshFreqPar;
            _Results = new Dictionary<Tuple<TasksTypes, string>, object>();
            TasksToDo = new List<Tuple<TasksTypes, string>>();
        }
        public void AddTask(TasksTypes type, string Insructions)
        {
            //<summary>Adds task to thread execution</summary>
            TasksToDo.Append<Tuple<TasksTypes, string>>(new Tuple<TasksTypes, string>(type, Insructions));
        }
    }
```

The code is executes just fine, no exceptions but still nothing appends,
Thanks.

Comment: Initializing a static field in an instance constructor is weird. And evil.

Comment: Worth noting [`Append` remarks `This method does not modify the elements of the collection. Instead, it creates a copy of the collection with the new element.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.append?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks)

Answer (score 7):

`List<T>` does not contain an `Append` method. You are using `Enumerable<T>.Append`, so that line essentially does nothing at all.

You would have to either store the result of the operation (which would mean enumerating and recreating the entire list every time that method is called):

```
TasksToDo = TasksToDo
    .Append<Tuple<TasksTypes, string>>(new Tuple<TasksTypes, string>(type, Insructions))
    .ToList();
```

Or much better yet, use `List<T>.Add`:

```
TasksToDo.Add(new Tuple<TasksTypes, string>(type, Insructions));
```